# SQL: WITH ROLLUP per department without totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some SQL needed for creating a file for export. I have a lot of it working as it should. The one major stumbling block is with the `WITH ROLLUP` portion.

I need to get totals by VendorNo(store) and by DepartmentID(dept), but not with overall totals. The Department is gleaned by getting the first 3 digits of a column as you can see below. Grouping on that as well as the VendorNo is giving me what I need but also throwing overall totals in there.

How can I either pare out the overall totals from `WITH ROLLUP` OR rewrite some portions to accomplish the same totaling per VendorNo, Dept?

So far, I have:

```
select 
    'VDP' as [Record Id],
    'TRU' as [Client Id],
    o.vendorNo as [Store Number],
    CASE WHEN LEFT(HVI.EncodeData, 3) IS NULL THEN 'S' ELSE 'D' END as [Feed Level],
    LEFT(HVI.EncodeData, 3) AS [DepartmentId],
    CONVERT(Date, pto.PrintBatch) as [Metric Date], 
    CASE WHEN pto.pickbit = 1 THEN 'ISPU_ORDER_PICKUP' ELSE 'ISPU_ORDER_CREATED' END as [Metric ID], -- 15 chars ISPU_ORDER_CREATED or ISPU_ORDER_PICKUP TOTO: VALIDATE THIS WORKS !!
    'A' AS [Metric Category],
    'D' AS [Metric Granularity],
    REPLICATE('0', 9 - len(CAST(SUM(OI.Quantity) AS int))) + CAST(CAST(SUM(OI.Quantity) as Int)as VARCHAR) AS [Data Value 1], -- needed to get the left-padded 9 char max value
    NULL as [Data Value 2],
    NULL as [Data Value 3],
    NULL as [Data Value 4],
    NULL as [Data Value 5],
    NULL as [Data Value 6],
    NULL as [Operation Code]
FROM 
    pickticketsorders pto
    inner join orders o 
        on pto.orderno = o.orderno 
        and o.rank = 3
        and pto.printbatch >= '6-12-2015' 
        and pto.printbatch <  '6-13-2015'
    INNER JOIN HostVendorItems HVI
        on HVI.ItemId = pto.ItemId
    INNER JOIN OrderItems OI
        on OI.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
GROUP BY 
    o.VendorNo, 
    LEFT(HVI.EncodeData, 3),
    pto.PrintBatch,
    pto.PickBit
    WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY 
    o.VendorNo, 
    DepartmentId , 
    pto.PrintBatch
```

Which gives me: (the line that has `StoreNo` as NULL needs to be removed)
[image: Screenshot of query results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUPING SETS`.  I am not sure exactly which groups you want, but this seems to match what you are asking for:

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((o.VendorNo, LEFT(HVI.EncodeData, 3), pto.PrintBatch, pto.PickBit),
                        (o.VendorNo, LEFT(HVI.EncodeData, 3)),
                        (o.VendorNo)
                       )
```

You might want to read more about `GROUPING SETS` in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could also add :

```
HAVING GROUPING(o.VendorNo) = 0
```